# How to merge the elements from a list into another list in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I have two lists like this:

```
list_1 = [100,100,50,40,40,10,20]
list_2 = [5,25,50,120]
```

I want to take all the elements from list_2 and add it to the end of list_1, also making it a nested list. The output should be like this:

```
[[100,100,50,40,40,10,20,5],[100,100,50,40,40,10,20,25],[100,100,50,40,40,10,20,50],[100,100,50,40,40,10,20,5,120]]
```

Is there any possible way of doing this in Python3?

Comment: what about `[list_1+[x] for x in list_2]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just create a list of lists with `list_1` added to a single element list made of each element of `list_2`:

```
list_1 = [100,100,50,40,40,10,20]
list_2 = [5,25,50,120]

list_3 = [list_1+[x] for x in list_2]

print(list_3)
```

result:

```
[[100, 100, 50, 40, 40, 10, 20, 5], [100, 100, 50, 40, 40, 10, 20, 25], [100, 100, 50, 40, 40, 10, 20, 50], [100, 100, 50, 40, 40, 10, 20, 120]]
```